# Error when trying to run nvidia-settings and nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I've installed `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-346 drivers` on my Asus K550J with intel integrated card and nvidia geforce gtx850m..
When I try to use `nvidia-settings` on the terminal it says:

```
cirelli@cirelli-pc:~$ sudo nvidia-settings
** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

How to fix this?